# Symfony - Dependencies not injecting in my entity listener class

Tags: php, symfony, dependencies, code-injection, autowired

My autowiring is not working for a basic file entity listener.

I have a File entity class which uses annotations to specify the listener, like:

```
/**

@Orm\Entity(repositoryClass="root\CoreBundle\Repository\FileRepository")
@Orm\EntityListeners({"root\CoreBundle\EventListener\Entity\FileEntityListener"})
@Orm\Table(
etc...
```

The FileEntityListener class starts off as follows:

```
class FileEntityListener
{
private $encoderFactory;
private $logger;

public function __construct(FilesystemMap $filesystemMap, LoggerInterface $logger)
{
    $this->setFilesystemMap($filesystemMap);
    $this->logger = $logger;
}
```

When the listener kicks in, the dependencies aren't injecting into the constructor of the listener and I get an error for the constructor, saying:

```
Type error: Too few arguments to function Epcvip\CoreBundle\EventListener\Entity\FileEntityListener::__construct(), 0 passed in /var/www/html/accounting/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Mapping/ContainerAwareEntityListenerResolver.php on line 83 and exactly 2 expected
```

The bundle is autowired and yet the dependencies are not being injected.

Would anyone know why this isn't working? Maybe a slight configuration step I am missing?

Comment: Assigning an entity listener via annotation is for older versions of Doctrine.  Use the approach described here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/entity-listeners.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tag your entity listener like this in services.yaml:

`services:
    root\CoreBundle\EventListener\Entity\FileEntityListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener }`

Comment: PS. Do not annotate the entity with @EntityListeners if you're going with this solution.

Comment: This doesn't work for us when we have Doctrine caching setup in `doctrine.yaml`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the doctrine listener `@Orm\EntityListeners()`. Autowiring works only for the symfony listener.

Delete the listener-annotation in your entity and add the following annotation to you listener as described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-entity-listeners)